# canon lide does not scan the bottom of the page in text mode

Tags: canon, scanner, sane, simplescan

When I scan a page in **text** mode, only the top 70-80% of the page is scanned (regardless of page settings; my paper is letter size, the page setting is letter, but the same result happens with a4 & legal).

When I scan the exact same page in **picture** mode, the whole page is scanned successfully.

Observed with both `xsane` and `simple-scan`.
Hardware: `CanoScan LiDE 110`.

Similar to https://askubuntu.com/q/675917/80483, also reported as [canon lide does not scan the bottom of the page in text mode](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/simple-scan/+bug/1560719).

Comment: Is your scanner connected over network or USB? I don't know that I'd be able to help, but this info might be helpful for someone else who can help you.

Comment: @AndroidDev: usb (simplescan does not support network scanners, I think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting resolution to 300dpi instead of 600dpi avoids the problem.
See [Canon Lide 210 aspect-ratio-problem at 600 dpi](http://lists.alioth.debian.org/pipermail/sane-devel/2014-May/032318.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Just run into this problem with my Canon CanoScan LiDE 110 in Linux Mint 18.3 (based on Ubuntu 16.04), which carries sane-backends at a git revision somewhere around 1.0.25. The problem was fixed by compiling from source and installing sane-backends 1.0.27.

Before trying this I suggest to take a system snapshot with something like [Timeshift](https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift), just in case something goes wrong.

1. install prerequisites for building:

`apt install libusb-dev build-essential libsane-dev libavahi-client-dev libavahi-glib-dev`

2. find where sane backends are currently installed:

`find /usr/lib -name 'libsane-*'`

3. in my case, the previous command lists files in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/`; I remove the trailing `/sane/` and keep note of the remaining path: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`
4. download sane-backends-1.0.27.tar.gz from [SANE GitLab project page](https://gitlab.com/sane-project/backends/uploads/a3ba9fff29253a94e84074917bff581a/sane-backends-1.0.27.tar.gz)
5. create a directory, untar, configure, make and install:

```
sudo su
mkdir /root/sane
cd /root/sane
mv /download/path/of/sane-backends-1.0.27.tar.gz .
tar xzvf /path/to/sane-backends-1.0.27.tar.gz
cd sane-backends-1.0.27
./configure BACKENDS="genesys" --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --enable-avahi
make
make install
```

6. now check that `scanimage --version` returns version 1.0.27 for both scanimage and backend

**IMPORTANT**: from what I see in my system, the above may remove all the other backends installed in your system. If you have other scanners from different brands, you may need to make other backends, not just genesys (which is the one needed for most CanoScan LiDE devices). Either remove `BACKENDS="genesys"` configure parameter or add the additional required backends there.

**NOTE**: this procedure was somewhat inspired by [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompileSaneFromSource), which suggests to add also `--prefix=/usr` configure parameter, which will cause sane backends to be installed into /usr/local instead of /usr. `scanimage` then didn't work for me.